# How to identify a Specific WebElement which is a child of WebTable in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I have a WebTable, which has some WebElements. I want to verify the text of one of the WebElements and take action on it. Can you help, how to proceed on this?

Comment: Did you mean "verify the te**x**t" rather than "te**s**t"?

Answer (score 3):

As Vinoth said if you know which row and column the element is in you can use `ChildItem`.

Typically UFT *flattens* the elements (so that a `WebElement` in a `WebTable` will appear as the `WebTable`s sibling if both are added to the repository. However something that many people do not know is that if you manually put an element under the `WebTable` (or any other element) then UFT will look for it under the parent object.

This means that you can describe the nested element and UFT will only look under the table and not in the rest of the page.

```
Browser("B").Page("P").WebTable("T").WebElement("innertext:=.*bla.*").Click
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ChildItem` method of `WebTable`.

```
Set MyWebElement = Browser("CreationTime:=0").Page("micclass:=Page").Webtable("name=TableName").ChildItem(Row, Column, micclass, Index)
```

- Row - Required. A long integer value.
  The row number where the cell is located. The first row in the table is numbered 1.
- Column - Required. A long integer value.
  The column number where the cell is located. The first column in the table is numbered 1.
- MicClass - Required. A String value.
  The object type.
- Index - Required. A long integer value.
  The index of the object of type MicClass in the cell. This index indicates the desired element when there is more then one object of type MicClass in the cell. The first object has an index of 0.

---

`MyWebElement` is the element you wanted. You can access any methods/properties of `WebElement`. For ex, to click,

```
MyWebElement.Click
```

Comment: Thanks Vinoth. But the Issue is, when i observe the properties of the webtable, it shows 0 rows and 0 records, but when i do a spy on the object , its parent is shown as a webtable. That is where the confusion lies.